# Android Game Programing

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm learning how to make an Android game from [this tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/hello-world---basic-example.html), but my app does not run. I'm debugging it on a Samsung Galaxy S2 (not on an emulator)

This is my logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demoandengine/com.example.demoandengine.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demoandengine.MainActivity

From the console:

```
[2014-03-08 23:12:11 - DemoAndengine] Starting activity com.example.demoandengine.MainActivity on device 1748080c
[2014-03-08 23:12:12 - DemoAndengine] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[ xxx ] cmp=xxxx }
[2014-03-08 23:12:56 - DemoAndengine] ------------------------------
[2014-03-08 23:12:56 - DemoAndengine] Android Launch!
[2014-03-08 23:12:56 - DemoAndengine] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-08 23:12:56 - DemoAndengine] Performing com.example.demoandengine.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-08 23:12:56 - DemoAndengine] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-03-08 23:12:59 - DemoAndengine] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-03-08 23:12:59 - AndEngine] **Could not find AndEngine.apk!**
[2014-03-08 23:12:59 - DemoAndengine] Starting activity com.example.demoandengine.MainActivity on device 1748080c
[2014-03-08 23:13:00 - DemoAndengine] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[ xxx ] cmp=xxxx }
```

I think that either my `AndEngine` lib has a problem or I'm importing the incorrect `AndEngine`.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Also check your manifest file for the activity to be declared.

Comment: Are there any errors in your project list? AndEngine or your project can have big red ! or x which has different meanings.